# I want to check if first column contains textbox1 and display full row in listview

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am new to C#, so forgive me if the answer is obvious, I want to connect to my SQL Server Management Studio and display items in listview if c.CompanyName contains given text in textBox1. There is probably an error but I can't find it. Help kindly appreciated.

```
SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection("Initial Catalog=Northwind;Data Source=localhost;Integrated Security=SSPI;");

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cnn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT c.CompanyName, o.Freight FROM Customers c INNER JOIN Orders o ON c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID WHERE c.CompanyName LIKE %@recherche%", cnn);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@recherche", textBox1.Text);
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (dr.HasRows)
    {
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            string companyname = dr.GetString(0);
            string salary = dr.GetDecimal(1).ToString();

            ListViewItem rowadd = listView1.Items.Add(companyname);
            rowadd.SubItems.Add(salary);
        }
    }

    cnn.Close();
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Are you getting error because you didnt add the ToString() method??- "textBox1.Text.ToString()"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT c.CompanyName, o.Freight FROM Customers c INNER JOIN Orders o ON c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID WHERE c.CompanyName LIKE @recherche", cnn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@recherche", "%" + textBox1.Text + "%");
```

Answer (score 0):

change your command to this:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("
    SELECT c.CompanyName, o.Freight
    FROM Customers c
        INNER JOIN Orders o ON c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
    WHERE c.CompanyName LIKE '%' + @recherche + '%'
", cnn);
```